# Triangle Breadcrumbs in Android

Tags: android, breadcrumbs, android-imagebutton

Am new to android. Dont know whether this question is too naive. The app that i am  currently working on requires triangle style breadcrumbs like:

[image]

The color of the triangle should change at each page.

I followed [this tutorial](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/) but couldn't transform a shape to a rectangle with cutting edges. I tried to add a triangle shape imageButton with transparent background and tried to change the background color but it fills the entire image .

provide some suggestions please.

Comment: Why don't you use a couple of overlayed images? Or (even simplier) a 9 patch background and then 3 transparent TextViews?

Comment: Or you want the color to be changed upon selection? This would be a problem.

Comment: Yaa the color needs to be changed upon selection also according to my app design different users have different background colors. So the color of the buttons will also change among different users. So am hesitating to use images for the breadcrumbs. Any other suggestions.?